# 603 HTTP response while using at commands

Tags: https, embedded, arduino-uno, gsm, at-command

I am using AT commands to get a response but when I run it I get 603 status message
these are the at commands

```
AT
OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","internet"
OK
AT+SAPBR=1,1
OK
AT+HTTPINIT
OK
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1
OK
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","https://otaupdates.onrender.com/update-sensor-data/1234567"
OK
AT+HTTPACTION=0
OK

+HTTPACTION: 0,603,0
```

I can't seem to work around it

Comment: You should specify what you are talking to.  Most AT commands are proprietary.  Looks like a SIM800 command, but you should be clear on that nonetheless.  Also kind of off-topic in any case.  Sending commands to device is not on its own a programming or software development problem.

Comment: ... and SO used markdown syntax for formatting messages.  Fixed the AT command/response list for you.

Comment: @Clifford it is actually [on topic on this site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403258/11336762).

Comment: @RobertoCaboni - perhaps, but the meta question has only two responses, so hardly a consensus.  The consensus as much as it is sems to be that questions about AT Command _may_ be on topic.  I am in agreement with Lundin's response in the last paragraph  I don't really object to the question - I welcome any interesting question, and have a high bar to vote down or  close-vote a question - seems rather punitive and petty for questions that are mostly harmless.  I object to anyone thinking that this is programming though.  It is an RTFM question at best - your answer even says as much.

Comment: @cliffort it seems to me that the two responses in meta questions fully cover the possibilities: yes and no. :) Though this specific question apparently resolves to a RTFM answer, this is not true in general for at-command questions. As I answered in a meta comment, this is not programming but it is something programmers have to deal with, for example like... Git. Would you remove Git questions from SO? ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to [SIM800 AT Command guide](https://www.elecrow.com/wiki/images/2/20/SIM800_Series_AT_Command_Manual_V1.09.pdf) (just to pick one module type, confident on fact that the others modules have a quite similar description) the error you experience have the following description:

> 603  DNS Error

So the host name you provided for some reason cannot be resolved to an IP address.
Since I'm actually able to *ping* it I suspect the reason might be in the fact you are accessing a TLS secured host, so make sure to configure correctly your device for HTTPS connections (`+HTTPS*` commands).

Finally I suggest, if it's possible, to start the development of your application using non-secured hosts, and only after all is fine to 'upgrade' the development to HTTPS sites.